# Need a small example on how to write a function in clojure

Tags: clojure

Need a small example on how to write a function taking a string param (like [id]) and return that string with a random int attached to it (id-123))

Comment: Random or unique?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```clj
(defn rand-id [id] 
  (str id "-" (rand-int 999)))

(rand-id "id")
```